# How do I serve firebase functions from a custom domain?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a website that I'm already running on firebase hosting using a google domain. I would like to now show all calls to my firebase function being made through a url such as api.mydomain.com, instead of the default firebase domain. How is it that I may be able to do this?

I read the firebase tutorial on [hosting cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#create_an_http_function_to_your_hosting_site), and I also came across [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#add_additional_sites) on creating multiple sites. So could someone please tell how is it that I can set up the workflow such that my site is still running at mydomain.com, but my APIs are now being called through api.mydomain.com? What would be the target name for

If possible, I Would like all requests to be shown as requests to api.mydomain.com, and not to api.mydomain.com/endpoint - so that what endpoint is being hit is also hidden from public

Sorry, I am new to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say your main project has an ID of `example-app`. To serve requests as `api.mydomain.com`, you would have to use a Cloud Function that makes use of `express` (or some other similar route handler).

1. Create the secondary site for your project using the Firebase CLI, (with an id of `example-app-api`, `example-api`, etc.)

```
firebase hosting:sites:create example-app-api
```

2. Connect your hosting targets to your resources

```
firebase target:apply hosting app example-app
firebase target:apply hosting api example-app-api
```

3. Modify your `firebase.json` file (located at the root of the firebase project) to suit the targets above.

```json
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      // app is linked to example-app, served as mydomain.com
      "target": "app",

      // contents of this folder are deployed to the site "example-app"
      "public": "public",

      // ... other settings ...
    },
    {
      // api is linked to example-app-api, served as api.mydomain.com
      "target": "api",

      // Contents of this folder are deployed to the site "example-app-api"
      // Any file here will be returned instead of calling your Cloud Function.
      // Recommended contents:
      //   - favicon.ico        (website icon for bookmarks, links, etc)
      //   - robots.txt         (instructions for bots and scrapers)
      // Optional contents:
      //   - service-worker.js  (empty file, used to prevent triggering cloud function)
      //   - humans.txt         (details about who you/your company are & how to report bugs)
      "public": "api-static-resources",  

      // ... other settings ...

      "rewrites": [
        {
          // redirect all calls to the function called "api"
          "source": "**",
          "function": "api"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

4. Deploy the `api` hosting config using the Firebase CLI

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:api
```

5. Open [Hosting Settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/hosting/main) for your project, click "View" for `example-app-api` then click "Custom Domain" following [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#add-domain).
6. You should now be able to trigger your Cloud Function by calling it at `api.mydomain.com`.

```
api.mydomain.com/getPost?id=someId
api.mydomain.com/favicon.ico
api.mydomain.com/robots.txt
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this is an awesome answer! I'm just a little confused in step 3: would I modify the firebase.json file for my node.js function? or for the actual website?

Comment: This is the `firebase.json` in your project directory where your code is deployed from. If you are using a file named `firebase.json` for your hosted site (that contains your `appId`, `databaseURL`, etc), Firebase Hosting makes the configuration file for you at `/__/firebase/init.json` or `/__/firebase/init.js` (see [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration) for more info)

Comment: thanks for clarifying - but I have deployed by backend code from another directly, and my actual website from a separate one. Do I change the firebase.json file for my website or for my firebase function in this case? From what you described, it is for the website correct?

Comment: The project `firebase.json` file (at `$PROJECT_DIR/firebase.json`) is used to configure deployment settings for when you use `firebase deploy`. While it is used to configure your project, it is not actually deployed with your code. In your Cloud Functions folder (default: `$PROJECT_DIR/functions`), you don't need any `firebase.json` - you can just use `admin.initializeApp()` (no arguments). In your Hosting folder (default: `$PROJECT_DIR/public`) you don't need a `firebase.json` file as `init.json`/`init.js` as above handles it for you.

Comment: If you have two different project directories, then you would put the above changes onto the `firebase.json` where you deploy your hosting site from.

Comment: Agree with @saladass4254, this is a fantastic answer! Thanks a lot for this, @samthecodingman!